# Easyjet car seat requirements

Tags: children, easyjet

On easyjet, are there some known requirements for car seats, other than the pretty minimal ones stated on [their website](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/boarding-and-flying/flying-with-children)?

> Only forward facing seats are allowed on board and the crew must be
>   able to secure it safely to the aircraft seat. If you don’t intend to
>   use your car seat on board please check it into the hold at the Bag
>   Drop desks.

Also, does anyone know what happens if the crew is not able *to secure it safely to the aircraft seat*? I'd assume they'd move the car seat to the hold free of charge since the Bag Drop is no longer an option at that time.

---

Unfortunately I have already tried the easyjet online chat, which was unable to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are rules for child seats are set by EASA, the European Aviation Safety Agency, which easyJet must comply with.

EASA has a [page and linked PDF info](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/passengers/travelling-with-children) regarding approved seats, which must have a marking indicating compliance with one of:

- ECE R44-03 or later amendments
- Canadian CMVSS 213/213.1
- US FMVSS 213
- qualified for use in aircraft according to ‘TŰV/958-01/2001’

However, EASA gives the same disclaimer that the seat has to be "properly installed on the aircraft seat". Likely, nobody can guarantee that every child seat can fit in every possible aircraft seat and position.

Comment: On the linked site I see the words "recommends", "should be", "approximately", "strongly encourages" and finally "How this can be done depends on the individual airline." Are you absolutely certain that easyjet **must** or at least *does* comply with these recommendations?

Comment: @Peter Welcome to the EU! It's because EASA regulations have to be implemented through state aviation authorities, so somewhere in the EU there may be one state that hasn't aligned their regulations yet. [More info on the specific rule here](https://www.easa.europa.eu/faq/19167). If you want assurance, you're going to have to bring it up with UK CAA, whose website is unhelpful.